# If I write blocking code inside a Kotlin coroutine will it still block the thread?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

This question arose after extensive discussion with a coworker,

The issue is the following:

what I was doing before calling a synchronous method inside a suspendCoroutine block with continuation:

```
private suspend fun <T : Any> request(queryRequest: GraphQLQueryRequest<T>): T? = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    val response = graphqlClient.executeQuery(queryRequest.query, queryRequest.variables, executor)
    val item = response.extractValueAsObject("data.${queryRequest.pathAccessor}", queryRequest.type.java)
    continuation.resume(item)
}
```

He claimed that my code was not preventing the thread from being blocked and the whole process would have to wait my coroutine resume to release the thread.

What he proposed:

```
private suspend fun <T : Any> request(queryRequest: GraphQLQueryRequest<T>): T? {
    val response = graphqlClient.reactiveExecuteQuery(queryRequest.query, queryRequest.variables, executor)
    return response.awaitSingle().extractValueAsObject("data.${queryRequest.pathAccessor}", queryRequest.type.java)
}
```

reactiveExecuteQuery() will return WebFlux Mono, then we call `.awaitSingle()` to convert Mono into a suspend function, he claims that this method unlike the first one will not block the thread and everything will work just fine.

according to [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) for suspendCoroutine

`Obtains the current continuation instance inside suspend functions and suspends the currently running coroutine.`

Does anyone with more insight into Kotlin coroutines know if those solution really provide different results? in terms of blocking of no blocking threads?

If that is not a use case for suspendCoroutine what would it be?

Thank you in advance for any replies :)

Comment: What is the graphql client you are using? If the executeQuery is not a suspending function, then your colleague is right. Your solution would block a thread.

Comment: suspendCoroutine is used to convert callback based APIs to coroutines

Comment: "Don't block the event bus" - I don't think it's a good design to block in coroutines.  Let Kotlin manage them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You coworker was generally right, as @Martin Tarjányi already mentioned.

`awaitSingle` is a suspending function, as you can see in the [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-reactive/kotlinx.coroutines.reactive/await-single.html). It means that invoking it will suspend the coroutine, but other coroutines can still run on the same Dispatcher.

Sometimes, there is no other solution, when a library provides only blocking API, but then you should be running your coroutines on a relatively large thread pool. With your code, you would run on the same dispatcher your `request()` is invoked from, usually `Dispatchers.Default`, which equals to the number of your cores (or 2 in case you run on a single core CPU).

Comment: You can mitigate the problem when you have to call blocking code by wrapping it in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` since IO has a relatively large thread pool.